# How to display attributes of features intersecting the Atlas feature in a Print Composer label?

Tags: qgis, atlas

Is it possible to edit labels with python or an expression?

I have an atlas layer and a shape with countries. the atlas layer has several features and each feature intersects with several countries.

I want a label on my pdf map that gets the country name (attribute in country layer) as a function of the intersection of the atlas layer. is something like this possible?

Example:
Feature 1 of Atlas Layer lays over 3 Countries (C1, C2, C3). I want a label on my map that says: "C1, C2, C3".
Feature 1 of Atlas Layer lays over 2 Countries (C5, C6). I want a label on my map that says: "C5, C6".

Answer (score 5):

Also as a variation of an answer to [How to count points within the current Print composer atlas feature in QGIS 2.8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152296/how-to-count-points-within-the-current-print-composer-atlas-feature-in-qgis-2-8/152543) , from QGIS 2.16 onwards you can list attributes intersecting an atlas feature within the Expression Editor, using the `aggregate()` function with the `concatenate` calculation and `within($geometry,@atlas_geometry)` as the filter.

Click on the 'Insert Expression' button in your text box properties and use an expression like the one below, replacing the attribute/layer name/concatenator (`,`) as required.:

```
aggregate('LAYER_NAME','concatenate',"ATTRIBUTE",
              intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry), ',')
```

If `ATTRIBUTE` field is a numeric datatype you may need to use `to_string("ATTRIBUTE")` instead of just plain `"ATTRIBUTE"` to allow concatenation.

As a bonus you can add additional filters within the same expression, e.g. `within($geometry,@atlas_geometry) AND "PPP" > 50000` for countries within the atlas geometry, where the PPP is also over 50k.

---

**QGIS 3.8 onwards**: Using additional aggregate array functions in QGIS 3 you have more flexibility with displaying attributes.

To have your list of concatenated attributes sorted by attribute name (see also [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327487/98784)), showing only unique values, you could use:

```
aggregate('LAYER_NAME','concatenate_unique',"ATTRIBUTE",
              intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry), ',', "ATTRIBUTE")
```

Arrays will let you slice and dice the list which is useful if you have limited space. The expression below will return a comma-separated list of the selected attribute from the first **three** intersecting features (`0,2`).

```
array_to_string(
    array_slice(
            aggregate('LAYER','array_agg',"ATTRIBUTE",
                      intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry))
     ,0,2)
,',')
```

---

If you want to get attributes from features intersecting the **extent of a layout map item** (but not necessarily intersecting with the atlas geometry) - for example if your coverage layer is a point layer, or you have a 10% buffer around your atlas feature in Atlas settings - instead of `@atlas_geometry` you can extract the extent of the layout map item using `item_variables()` as below:

```
aggregate('LAYER_NAME','concatenate_unique',"ATTRIBUTE",
              intersects($geometry,
              map_get(item_variables('LAYOUT_MAP_NAME'),'map_extent')), ',', "ATTRIBUTE")
```

Note you may need to change the name of your layout map item from the default name (e.g. `Map 1`)

See below example showing attributes and count of the line features intersecting with the `inserts` map item - `map_get(item_variables('inserts'),'map_extent')` - even though the atlas itself is driven by a point layer (and @atlas_geometry would be of no use here).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a variation of [How to count points within the current Print composer atlas feature in QGIS 2.8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152296/how-to-count-points-within-the-current-print-composer-atlas-feature-in-qgis-2-8/152543#152543) try this:

Create an expression script in the Expression Function Editor with this code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def getAttribudeIntersectAtlasFeature(intersectLayername, intersectFieldname, geomAtlas, feature, parent):
    # If geomAtlas is empty, return empty string
    if (geomAtlas is None):
        return ''

    # Get layer reference from layername
    intersectLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(intersectLayername)[0]

    # Raise if layer not found
    if intersectLayer is None:
        raise Exception("Layer not found: " + intersectLayername)

    # Count point within current Atlas feature
    countryname = ''
    for ft in intersectLayer.getFeatures():
        intersectGeom = ft.geometry()
        if (intersectGeom is None):
            continue
        if intersectGeom.intersects(geomAtlas):
            countryname += ft[intersectFieldname] + ','

    return countryname[:-1]
```

Then use the custom function in an label expression in the print composer:

```
[% getAttribudeIntersectAtlasFeature( 'world', 'country',  $atlasgeometry )%]
```

Where 'world' is the tabel with countries, 'country' is the columnname with the countryname and $atlasgeometry is the current atlas geometry.

Map:
[image: w]

Atlas 1:
[image: w2]

Atlas 2:
[image: w3]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this under the label's **Main Properties** in QGIS3:

```
array_to_string( aggregate('COUNTRY_LAYER','array_agg',"COUNTRY_NAME_FIELD",intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry)))
```

[image: QGIS3 label Main Properties]