# Using another shape database in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have an Atlas where I would like to use values from another shape, to quantify the number of points and use this number to control font size.

The shape that is controlling Atlas has a sequence of dates, the other shapes are called using the command "date" = @ atlas_pagename, in one of these shapes it has point information that I would like to use to generate number of points, and from from this number the source grows or decreases.

I know I can use the table feature asking for another shape as a source, but as I want to control font size, I would like to know if it is possible to call field values from another shape for that

Comment: Not an answer, as I get lost in all the shapes mentioned. I don't ḱnow if your data fits to this, but did you already try to simply use joining tables (I mean not physical but as a connection in QGIS). Or maybe use Virtual Layers. Once you found out how they work (and I hate SQL by heart!), there are really a lot of opportunities to crunch data on the fly. Good luck.

Comment: See if these answers help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152296/how-to-count-points-within-the-current-print-composer-atlas-feature-in-qgis-2-8 (counting features) and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268432/grouping-and-sorting-a-list-of-equipment-using-an-aggregate-function-in-the-prin (extracting attributes) and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268386/98784 (extracting attributes from map extent not just atlas geometry)