# QGIS using spatial query in the Layer Attribute Editor

Tags: qgis

I am currently setting up a table to capture polygons into a shapefile to show grounds maintenance areas.
One of the columns in the layer is the parish name. This is contained in another layer

In the grounds maintenance layer I can set the parish column to 'Value Relation' and specify the Parish layer and the relevant Key and Name column.
If I then capture a new record, I can then add the parish name. But I would need to have queried the parish layer first to have established the Parish name.

Is there a way of automating this process so that when I capture the new record into the Grounds Maintenance layer, the parish name is automatically populated. 
I know I can do a spatial join but I'd rather not have to do this as it would mean an additional step which is seperate from the main task of capturing the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can derive the parish name as a default value through an intersect with your feature layer with the parish names. therefore you will need a custom function in the expression builder. The code for this function could be like this one (QGIS3), which is more or less adapted from this post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/163608/87346):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def getAttributeIntersectFeature(intersectLayername, intersectFieldname, geom, feature, parent):
# If geom is empty, return empty string
if (geom is None):
    return ''

# Get layer reference from layername
intersectLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(intersectLayername)[0]

# Raise if layer not found
if intersectLayer is None:
    raise Exception("Layer not found: " + intersectLayername)

# Count intersection within current feature
attributename = ''
for ft in intersectLayer.getFeatures():
    intersectGeom = ft.geometry()
    if (intersectGeom is None):
        continue
    if intersectGeom.intersects(geom):
        attributename += ft[intersectFieldname] + ','

return attributename[:-1]
```

then use your function with the expression builder and put it in the default value section (in this example I derive the country name from a country layer):
[image]