# Summarize points by tag over each atlas feature with QGIS composer

Tags: qgis, atlas, count, aggregate

I'm trying to represent in every single atlas feature the basin for several streams.
Each basin can have one or more stations. The data to plot is a point vector, with columns for "data" and "LABEL" for each station where the data belongs to.

For statistical purposes, I've created an HTML label to count,for each atlas feature, the points with data for each station that are within each represented basin. I've followed the answer: [How to display attributes of features intersecting the Atlas feature in a Print Composer label?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155202/how-to-display-attributes-of-features-intersecting-the-atlas-feature-in-a-print/268386#268386)
, using the function proposed by *she_weeds*:

aggregate('LAYER_NAME','concatenate_unique',"ATTRIBUTE",intersects($geometry,@atlas_geometry), ',', "ATTRIBUTE")

It works, but due to the 'concatenate_unique' operator, when two stations have the same number of collected data (0 for example), only one value appears on the HTML label.

*F.e.: Nº of points with valid data for basin X for each one of its stations: 21,0,66.
But i know that this basin have 4 stations, so the answer should be: Nº of points with valid data for basin X for each one of its stations: 21,0,0,66.*

Comment: Would it help to use 'concatenate' instead of 'concatenate_unique'?

Comment: That only shows each attribute value for each intersecting feature separated by commas...imaging 66 values showed that way when I only want that value: 66 for 1 station. Or 66,25 for 2 stations.

Comment: I think maybe you need to aggregate the stations by ID separately from the actual count of valid data? I'm not entirely clear how your station data is structured, if you could share a sample of your data and fields and the exact expression you used (i.e. which fields did you aggregate using), that would make it easier to help.

Comment: sorry, I'm newbie, how can i share a file with you in a private way?

Comment: Are you able to take a screenshot and just blank out the relevant sections or show dummy data instead? There's unfortunately no easy way to share files privately on GIS.SE. The actual data itself is not that important, just the structure and what you're trying to achieve. For example do you have basin layer, station layer, and station data layer. Or do you just have station data layer with station ID field and you have been grouping by that.

Comment: Ok. I have a basin layer and the station data with an ID for each one. So i need for each station/s inside each basin(each basin is an atlas feature on the QGIS composer), the count of available data for a parameter: having numerical, NULL, an string values (e.g, <5.0).

Comment: The issue: when a basin has two stations with the same amount of to_real(data) (e.g, 0 valid data) the aggregate function you've proposed shows only one '0' count, but i need a function that shows '0,0' as total data for a larger set of points of null data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149037/discussion-between-pablo-xesteira-and-she-weeds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion it appears the question is about aggregating data on another layer that is within an atlas feature, grouped by another field. As the data is on another layer it has to be aggregate either using `aggregate()` or one of the `overlay_` functions, but there is no access to a further data field to group the results by, only filter.

The OP's workaround was to use those functions to aggregate an aggregate (i.e. instead of `overlay_intersects('data_points',"data_field")`, use `overlay_intersects('data_points',count("data_field",group_by:="aggregate_field"))` - the inner aggregate function, `count()` in this instance, lets you nominate a field to group by. But you still get a result for each feature that is within the atlas feature.

So for example if within your first atlas feature you have 3 points in station A, 2 points in station B, and 3 points in station C, the result is `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` . Applying `array_distinct()` or similar to that yields `[3, 2]` when the desired result is `[3, 2, 3]`.

One specific solution to that is to add the aggregate field back in to differentiate the first set of 3 from the second set of 3, by concatenating it to the inner aggregate to get for example `[A3, A3, A3, B2, B2, C3, C3, C3]`. Then apply `array_distinct()` or similar to get `[A3, B2, C3]` and go from there.

---

Example data:

[image]

Use the following expression - you can add an optional extra filter parameter after `"station_id"` in the `count()` function, the example below has `"data_field" > 20`

`array_to_string(array_distinct(overlay_contains('data_points',"station_id"||': '||count("data_field","station_id"))),', ')`

Result:

[image]

---

The more elegant approach would probably be to use attribute tables where suitable though, as shown above - use the `count()` expression as an attribute.

Comment: Hurray! Eureka! You did it! It works just the way i've been searching for! I think my fault was to focuss on try to count points, instead of grouping it on a first step. Thank you very much!