# QGIS layout; Sum values in layout attribute table only in map window

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, layouts

I have produced a layout showing the polygons of grass verges to cut, and have placed an attribute table listing name and area (in m2) on the layout. I have selected 'show only features visible within a map'.  Is there a way I can have a label which give the total of the area's in the attribute table on the layout only (not the total area of all the polygons in the layer, just those in the map window).

Comment: Check out this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268386/98784 and scroll to the part about the extent of a map layout item. And change the aggregate function from `'concatenate_unique'` to `'sum'`