# Counting points in polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point-in-polygon, count

Is there any simple integration for calculating count of points in polygon using QGIS-Python integration?

In other words, are there any pre-defined functions for points in polygon of QGIS using python, so that we can use them in our python script?

Comment: Great questions, although It would be best to wrap these questions into a single question.

Comment: You can find some parallel code in this question counting points in current atlas feature: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152296/how-to-count-points-within-the-current-print-composer-atlas-feature-in-qgis-2-8/152543#152543

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great methods already posted! There are also tools from the **Processing Toolbox** which you could call from your script (this is assuming you are running scripts *inside* QGIS):

- Count points in polygon
- Counts points in polygon (weighted)
- Count unique points in polygon

Taking the first tool, you could call it using:

```
import processing

Result = "path\to\saved_output.shp"
processing.runalg("qgis:countpointsinpolygon", "path\to\polygon_layer.shp", "path\to\point_layer.shp", 'NUMPOINTS', Result)
```

where `NUMPOINTS` is the name of the field which stores the number of points.

I'm using QGIS 2.8.2-Wien, Processing plugin v2.9.3. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

I rewrote my answer from a parallel question counting points in current atlas feature: [How to count points within the current Print composer atlas feature in QGIS 2.8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152296/how-to-count-points-within-the-current-print-composer-atlas-feature-in-qgis-2-8/152543#152543)

Build a new function in the expression editor:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface


@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
    def countPointsInPolygon(pointLayerName, geom, feature, parent):
        # If point geom is empty, return 0
        if (geom is None):
            return 0

        # Get point layer reference from layername
        pointLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(pointLayerName)[0]

        # Raise if layer not found
        if pointLayer is None:
            raise Exception("Layer not found: " + pointLayerName)

        # Count point within current polygon feature
        countPoint = 0
        for pointFeature in pointLayer.getFeatures():
            pointGeom = pointFeature.geometry()
            if (pointGeom is None):
                continue
            if pointGeom.within(geom):
                countPoint += 1

        return countPoint
```

Use it as a expression on the polygon layer where 'mypoints' is the name of the point layer: 
`countPointsInPolygon( 'mypoints',  $geometry )`

If you don't want it implemented as an expression, you can call the function from your own script looping the features of the polygon layer calling countPointsInPolygon for each feature.

Answer (score 2):

the most simple way is to use "Join attribute by location". You can do it from the menu (data managment > Join by location), or with Python ("qgis:joinbylocation") with the option "take summary of intersecting features", computing the sum of a field with "1" at each point.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with QGIS's python API, so my answer is a wild guess. But it [looks like](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html) QGIS is using GEOS geometry objects similar to django. So this could work in QGIS too:

```
len(geom.coords)
```

Comment: Good guess but that is not what I am asking. I have every thing points, polygon. what I just want is to calculate the points in the polygon using pyqgis

Answer (score 1):

I assume your polygon is a qgsfeature :

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html

I didn't test it but I guess it would work :

```
len(polygon.geometry().asPolygon())
```

polygon.geometry() gives a qgsgeometry class.

qgsgeometry.asPolygon() gives a list of the point of your polygon.

Edit : You want the points inside the polygon? You have points in an other layer and wonder which ones intersect your polygon?